# MEAN-Stack save an array in MongoDB with mongoose

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, mean-stack, meanjs

I am new to web development and I just ran into a problem I can't solve. I started with the [MEAN](http://meanjs.org/)-Stack so far and I encountered the following problem.

I have an array structure for a slider in my angular js Controller. From this array structure, I am trying to save a few values into my database.

Angular JS Controller snippet

```
$scope.alerts = [
    { id: 1,
      title: 'CustomerCount',
      value: 1,
      weight: 30,
      options: {
        showTicks: true,
        hidePointerLabels: true,
        hideLimitLabels: true,
        stepsArray: [
            { value: 1, legend: '<10' },
            { value: 2, legend: '<50' },
            { value: 3, legend: '<250' },
            { value: 4, legend: '<500' },
            { value: 5, legend: '>500' }

        ]
      }
    },
    { id: 2,
      title: 'CustomerSatisfaction',
      value: 3,
      weight: 40,
      options: {
        showTicks: true,
        hidePointerLabels: true,
        hideLimitLabels: true,
        stepsArray: [
            { value: 1, legend: '<10' },
            { value: 2, legend: '<50' },
            { value: 3, legend: '<250' },
            { value: 4, legend: '<500' },
            { value: 5, legend: '>500' }

        ]
      }
    }
];
```

From the above snippet, I'd like to save the **title**, the **value** and the **weight** of each alert in alerts

For this purpose, I have in the same angular js controller the following snippet

```
  // Create new Article object
  var article = new Articles({
    title: this.title,
    alert: this.alert,
  });
```

As far as I understand does this snippet create a new article entry in my database using the following schema defined in the server.model.js file

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema;

/**
 * Article Schema
 */
var ArticleSchema = new Schema({
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  alert: [{ value: Number, weight: Number, title: String }]
});


mongoose.model('Article', ArticleSchema);
```

But my Problem now is that this only saves an empty array in MongoDB.

The solution presented below lead to the solution. It has to be noted that

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema;

/**
 * Article Schema
 */
var ArticleSchema = new Schema({
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  alerts: []
});

  // Create new Article object
  var article = new Articles({
    title: this.title,
    alerts: this.alerts,
  });
```

Delivered the wanted solution!

Comment: Where are you calling the `save()` method on the model i.e. `article.save()`?

Comment: I have that in my article.server.controller.js file, which I did not list here but it looks like the one codeGig provided below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your schema to this and it should work:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema;

/**
 * Article Schema
 */
var ArticleSchema = new Schema({
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  alert: []
});


mongoose.model('Article', ArticleSchema);
```

I managed to save arrays in mongodb by just specifying `[]` in the schema and then you can save multiple objects in the array.

Comment: No that way the input in MongoDB is still an empty array. Or do I need to change `alert: this.alert,` this somehow?

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot!!! It works with arrays. The problem in this specific case is that it has to be `alerts: []` and `alerts: this.alerts` in order to work

Comment: This helped me as well. I was struggling with the same problem for almost a week before I found this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `save` method on the `Article` schema. Only then the article is saved

```
var article = new Articles({
 title: this.title,
 alert: this.alert,
});

article.save(function(err, doc){
  if(!err){
    // Article saved! "doc" is the reference
  }else{
    console.error('Error on saving the article');
  }
});
```

Here is the [mongoose save documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save) for reference

Comment: As codeGig stated is the coded mentioned already in my project. I am able to save data to mongoose but unfortunately the alert array is empty and not populated with the values I mentioned

Answer (score 0):

If You are using MEAN then Saving data comes on server which is handle on Express, Mongodb(Mongoose) and Nodejs.

I am assuming that you are using Meanjs of yo

First you need to make a route where which is called by your angular $http ajax
Route:
 **article.server.route.js**

```
 // Articles collection routes
  app.route('/api/articles')
    .post(articles.create);
```

Controller:
**article.server.controller.js**

```
exports.create = function (req, res) {
  var article = new Article(req.body);
  article.user = req.user;

  article.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        message: err
      });
    } else {
      res.json(article);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: I am using Mean js and I generated the project with yo. But I have already all the code you mentioned in my project which was generated by the yeoman generator. I can write data into mongoose, but the data in mongoose consists of an empty alert array rather then a populated one with the above defined values.