# How to properly push array values in a mongoose schema in MEAN

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

MEAN stack newbie here. I created a simple app that takes names and ages as practice. Right now I'm stumped at the part where I have to push array values into my mongoose array.

Here's my schema:

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    peoplelist : [{
        name: String,
        age: String
    }]
});
```

Here's my client-side controller:

```
app.controller("IndexController", function ($scope, $resource) {
    var PeopleAPI = $resource('/api/post/');

    // This is used by ng-repeat
    $scope.inputfields = [{
        infoname: '',
        infoage: ''
    }];

    // This will be used when transferring details to mongoose schema
    $scope.arrayppl= {
        name: '',
        details: [$scope.inputfields]
    };

    // Adds new fields in the UI - adding friends is unlimited.
    $scope.addDetails = function () {
        $scope.inputfields.push({});
    }


    $scope.saveToDB = function () {
        var people = new PeopleAPI();

        // save name to main array (arrayppl)
        $scope.arrayppl["name"] = $scope.username;

        // save infoname and infoage to arraymen
        var len = $scope.inputfields.length;

        for (var i = 0; i <= len - 1; i++) {
            var tempArr = {};
            tempArr["infoname"] = $scope.inputfields[i].infoname;
            tempArr["infoage"] = $scope.inputfields[i].infoage;

            $scope.arraymen["details"].push(tempArr);
        }

        people.name = $scope.arrayppl["name"];

        var i = 0;
        angular.forEach($scope.arraymen["details"], function (item) {

            var peopleObj = {name: item[i].infoname, age: item[i].infoage};

            people.peoplelist.push(peopleObj); // <-- error gets triggered here

            i+=1;
        });

        people.$save(function(result){
           console.log(result);
        });
    }
});
```

Here's a [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/cV2rYVP4Nz8e7wjJdtkR?p=preview) of what my app looks like, and the [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12676827/saving-an-array-property-on-a-mongoose-schema) I'm using as reference because it's the closest to what I'm trying to do.

At the `people.peoplelist.push(peopleObj)` line, I'm getting a `"Cannot read property 'push' of undefined.` error. Does this mean that I'm not properly getting my array schema from mongoose? How do I fix this?

Any replies would be very much appreciated.

Thank you as always for your guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this with the help of [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38783378/mean-stack-save-an-array-in-mongodb-with-mongoose) I had make some changes to my schema and client-side controller in order to make it work.

Here's what I did:

**My new schema:**

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    peoplelist : []
});
```

**My new controller:**

```
app.controller("IndexController", function ($scope, $resource) {
    var PeopleAPI = $resource('/api/post/');

    $scope.inputfields = [{
        infoname: '',
        infoage: ''
        }];

    $scope.arraymen = {
        name: '',
        details: []
    };

    $scope.addDetails = function () {
        $scope.inputfields.push({});
    }

    $scope.saveToDB = function () {
        var people = new PeopleAPI();

        // save name to main array (arraymen)
        $scope.arraymen["name"] = $scope.username;

        // save infoname and infoage to arraymen
        //var len = Object.keys($scope.inputfields.infoname).length;
        var len = $scope.inputfields.length;

        for (var i = 0; i <= len - 1; i++) {
            var tempArr = {};
            tempArr["infoname"] = $scope.inputfields[i].infoname;
            tempArr["infoage"] = $scope.inputfields[i].infoage;

            //$scope.arraymen["details"].push(tempArr);
            $scope.arraymen["details"].push({
                "name": tempArr["infoname"],
                "age": tempArr["infoage"]
            });
        }


        people.name = $scope.arraymen["name"];
        //people.peoplelist = new Array();
        people.peoplelist = [];


        for (var i = 0; i <= $scope.arraymen["details"].length - 1; i++) {
            people.peoplelist.push({
                name: $scope.arraymen["details"][i].name,
                age: $scope.arraymen["details"][i].age
            })

        }

        people.$save(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        });

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var people = new PeopleAPI(); is like object.
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

you are trying to push in object. push can work only array.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects